# 'Vocode' 'Self-hosted Telephony Server' example gives import error

Tags: python, pyngrok

The code originally worked, then it started the code gave me import error

My Code:

file main.py

```py
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import os
import uvicorn
import sys

from vocode.streaming.models.agent import ChatGPTAgentConfig
from vocode.streaming.models.message import BaseMessage
from vocode.streaming.models.telephony import TwilioConfig
from vocode.streaming.telephony.conversation.outbound_call import OutboundCall
from vocode.streaming.telephony.conversation.zoom_dial_in import ZoomDialIn
from vocode.streaming.telephony.server.base import InboundCallConfig, TelephonyServer
from vocode.streaming.models.synthesizer import ElevenLabsSynthesizerConfig, StreamElementsSynthesizerConfig
from memory_config import config_manager

from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# First we will open up our TelephonyServer, which opens a path at
# our BASE_URL. Once we have a path, we can request a call from
# Twilio to Zoom's dial-in service or any phone number.

# We need a base URL for Twilio to talk to:
# If you're self-hosting and have an open IP/domain, set it here or in your env.
BASE_URL = os.getenv("BASE_URL")

# If you're using Replit, open domains are handled for you.
if os.getenv('REPL_SLUG') is not None:
  BASE_URL = f"{os.getenv('REPL_SLUG')}.{os.getenv('REPL_OWNER')}.repl.co"

# If neither of the above are true, we need a tunnel.
if not BASE_URL:
  from pyngrok import ngrok
  ngrok_auth = os.environ.get("NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN")
  if ngrok_auth is not None:
    ngrok.set_auth_token(ngrok_auth)
  port = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--port") +
                  1] if "--port" in sys.argv else 3000

  # Open a ngrok tunnel to the dev server
  BASE_URL = ngrok.connect(port).public_url.replace("https://", "")
  logger.info("ngrok tunnel \"{}\" -> \"http://127.0.0.1:{}\"".format(
    BASE_URL, port))

# Now we need a Twilio account and number from which to make our call.
# You can make an account here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens#step-2-api-key
TWILIO_CONFIG = TwilioConfig(
  account_sid=os.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID") or "<your twilio account sid>",
  auth_token=os.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN") or "<your twilio auth token>",
)

# You can use your free number of buy a premium one here:
# https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search
# Once you have one, set it here or in your env.
TWILIO_PHONE = os.getenv("OUTBOUND_CALLER_NUMBER")

# We store the state of the call in memory, but you can also use Redis.
# https://docs.vocode.dev/telephony#accessing-call-information-in-your-agent
CONFIG_MANAGER = config_manager  #RedisConfigManager()

# Now, we'll configure our agent and its objective.
# We'll use ChatGPT here, but you can import other models like
# GPT4AllAgent and ChatAnthropicAgent.
# Don't forget to set OPENAI_API_KEY!
AGENT_CONFIG = ChatGPTAgentConfig(
  initial_message=BaseMessage(text="Hello, this is Ada from Arasaka"),
  prompt_preamble="You are playing as a arasaka agent from cp2077, calling about a cars (KIA Sportage 2017) extended warranty, the person name you are speaking to is Leslie",
  generate_responses=True,
  model_name="gpt-4"
)

# Now we'll give our agent a voice and ears.
# Our default speech to text engine is DeepGram, so you'll need to set
# the env variable DEEPGRAM_API_KEY to your Deepgram API key.
# https://deepgram.com/

# We use StreamElements for speech synthesis here because it's fast and
# free, but there are plenty of other options that are slower but
# higher quality (like Eleven Labs below, needs key) available in
# vocode.streaming.models.synthesizer.
# SYNTH_CONFIG = StreamElementsSynthesizerConfig.from_telephone_output_device()
SYNTH_CONFIG = ElevenLabsSynthesizerConfig.from_telephone_output_device(
  api_key=os.getenv("ELEVEN_LABS_API_KEY") or "<your EL token>",
  voice_id="EXAVITQu4vr4xnSDxMaL")

# Let's create and expose that TelephonyServer.
telephony_server = TelephonyServer(
  base_url=BASE_URL,
  config_manager=CONFIG_MANAGER,
  inbound_call_configs=[
    InboundCallConfig(url="/inbound_call",
                      agent_config=AGENT_CONFIG,
                      twilio_config=TWILIO_CONFIG,
                      synthesizer_config=SYNTH_CONFIG)
  ],
  logger=logger,
)
app.include_router(telephony_server.get_router())


# OutboundCall asks Twilio to call to_phone using our Twilio phone number
# and open an audio stream to our TelephonyServer.
def start_outbound_call(to_phone: Optional[str]):
  if to_phone:
    outbound_call = OutboundCall(base_url=BASE_URL,
                                 to_phone=to_phone,
                                 from_phone=TWILIO_PHONE,
                                 config_manager=CONFIG_MANAGER,
                                 agent_config=AGENT_CONFIG,
                                 twilio_config=TWILIO_CONFIG,
                                 synthesizer_config=SYNTH_CONFIG)
    outbound_call.start()


# Before we get started, you'll need a premium Zoom account that supports dial-in:
# https://zoom.us/zoomconference
ZOOM_NUMBER = "+16699006833"  # Zoom's San Jose number


def start_outbound_zoom(meeting_id: Optional[str],
                        meeting_password: Optional[str]):
  if meeting_id and meeting_password:
    call = ZoomDialIn(zoom_meeting_id=meeting_id,
                      zoom_meeting_password=meeting_password,
                      base_url=BASE_URL,
                      config_manager=CONFIG_MANAGER,
                      zoom_number=ZOOM_NUMBER,
                      from_phone=TWILIO_PHONE,
                      agent_config=AGENT_CONFIG,
                      synthesizer_config=SYNTH_CONFIG,
                      twilio_config=TWILIO_CONFIG,
                      transcriber_config=None)
    call.start()


# Expose the starter webpage
@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
  env_vars = {
    "BASE_URL": BASE_URL,
    "OPENAI_API_KEY": os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    "DEEPGRAM_API_KEY": os.environ.get("DEEPGRAM_API_KEY"),
    "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID": os.environ.get("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"),
    "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN": os.environ.get("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"),
    "OUTBOUND_CALLER_NUMBER": os.environ.get("OUTBOUND_CALLER_NUMBER")
  }

  return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
    "request": request,
    "env_vars": env_vars
  })


@app.post("/start_outbound_call")
async def api_start_outbound_call(to_phone: Optional[str] = Form(None)):
  start_outbound_call(to_phone)
  return {"status": "success"}


@app.post("/start_outbound_zoom")
async def api_start_outbound_zoom(
    meeting_id: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    meeting_password: Optional[str] = Form(None)):
  start_outbound_zoom(meeting_id, meeting_password)
  return {"status": "success"}


uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3000)
```

file memory_config.py

```
from vocode.streaming.telephony.config_manager.in_memory_config_manager import InMemoryConfigManager

config_manager = InMemoryConfigManager()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aweso\OneDrive\Desktop\SalesGPT\make_call.py", line 11, in <module>
    from vocode.streaming.telephony.conversation.outbound_call import OutboundCall
  File "C:\Users\aweso\OneDrive\Desktop\SalesGPT\env\Lib\site-packages\vocode\streaming\telephony\conversation\outbound_call.py", line 3, in <module>
    from vocode import getenv
ImportError: cannot import name 'getenv' from 'vocode' (C:\Users\aweso\OneDrive\Desktop\SalesGPT\env\Lib\site-packages\vocode\__init__.py)
```

I have tried the code before, and it worked until the error happend, the fastapi app started and you could call someone's number with an ai agent just like in the example here [Self Hosted Telephony Server](https://replit.com/@vocode/Self-hosted-Telephony-Server)

Comment: Do you have a file or folder in your project called "vocode"? If so, try renaming it.